# How to get editing text box to expand to fit size of string field

Tags: acumatica

I've noticed that in the Employee Time Cards screen (EP305000) in the details tab, there is a field called 'Summary' (In the DAC it's 'Subject') - and when you double click to edit the field, the edit area expands to show the entire text to be edited.

I have a custom screen with a grid, and this grid has text fields which I would like to have the same property as the Employee Time Card 'Subject' field (as described above), namely that when you enter the field to edit, it expands to show the entire text.

I've looked at the source DAC for the grid in EP305000, and I don't see anything that jumps out at me as an attribute on the 'Subject' field for that sort of thing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Removing the PXTextEdit RowTemplate element (field editor) removed that functionality. There could be more to it but you could try adding a PXTextEdit editor.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.  Added a RowTemplate with a PXTextEdit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a RowTemplate to the Grid area for the two fields I wanted to make expanded, as follows:

```
            <RowTemplate>
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="PXTextEdit1" runat="server" DataField="TodoDescription"/>
                <px:PXTextEdit ID="PXTextEdit2" runat="server" DataField="Comments"/>
            </RowTemplate>
```

This did the trick.  Thanks to HB_ACUMATICA for the answer.